# Matlab work with each vector from a 4D array

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing

I have a 4D matrix of size, let's say, 100x200x3x10 where 100x200 is the size of one image, 3 is the number of channels (RGB images) and 10 is the number of images.

I want to compute the inner product of each RGB vector in each image with itself. The resulting image should be of size 100x200x10. How can I efficiently compute these products, possibly without the use of loops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call your matrix `M`, this should work:

```
squeeze(dot(M,M,3))
```

The `squeeze` is because matlab gives a 100x200x1x10 matrix as the result, and `squeeze` knocks out the redundant dimension.